# JMeter - Setting the value of a Counter config element programatically in a setup thread

Tags: jmeter

Im using Jmeter 5.5. Im trying to find a way to set the starting value of a counter programmatically. Essentially what i need to do is

1. Start test
2. Read an int value from a file <-- setUpThreadGroup
3. Set the start value of the Counter element to this value.<-- setUpThreadGroup
4. Iterate through the test/threads, incrementing this as a shared variable. <--Threadgroup
5. Write the new value to the file. <-- Teardown

I've tried using props.put(),(__P,__setProperty), vars.put, System.setProperty, all with no success.

Is it possible to set the starting value of a counter via code?  It always seems to start with 0.

If this isnt possible, is it possible to create a shared variable that can be used across threads that increments safely to ensure no duplicate variable values will ever be used?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you even need set up and teardown thread groups, you can do something like:

1. Read the counter from the file via [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) like:

   ```
   ${__FileToString(counter.txt,,)}
   ```
2. Once all iterations are complete you can write the new value into the file using [__StringToFile() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringToFile)

   ```
   ${__StringToFile(counter.txt,${counter},false,)}
   ```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-counter)

Comment: Are you able to upload that jmx somewhere please? ive recreated it my side, your counter in your increments - mine does not. New here too - am trying to find a place to upload my screenshots to.